# What is the "Post is related to a rapidly changing event" flag?

Tags: support

Today I saw a [question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/20083/is-it-safe-to-go-to-icmeler-turkey-now) flagged with *Post is related to a rapidly changing event*, which I've never seen before and I liked very much.

What's the story? Who can flag it? only moderators? and what will happen to these questions? anything special we should know?

[image: flag]

Comment: I felt the same way! Very appropriate but somehow I'd never heard of it before and I usually read the blog and listen to the podcast.

Comment: It may have originated on Skeptics.SE: http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/549/handling-current-events

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it's a post notice that moderators can put on a question / answer. The idea is to give heads-up to visitors that information contained therein may change over a short period of time.

Naturally, *any* answer can change in correctness over time, but with things such as safety in a country due to civil unrest et al I felt it was a good use of the post notice to notify viewers of the situation.

PS - It's not a flag, it's a post notice.

Comment: I think you should be using this post notice more and more.. many questions fit under this category (rapidly changing). I wished if there is a way that users can vote for such a notice.

Comment: Indeed, I only recently noticed this option. If you feel a post should have a notice, flag it / ping me in chat!

Comment: For anyone wondering about the SE jargon term "post notice" I can't find any glossary or article specifically on the term. The best I can find is an old blog entry: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/09/bounty-reasons-and-post-notices/