# Event Based Effects?

Tags: discussion, tagging

Did I miss a discussion about this new tag, [event-based-effects](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/event-based-effects)? I am not sure it should be a tag (it smells a bit meta, like "homework" or "urgent") but if it should, perhaps current-events or temporary-situation would be better. I could not figure out what it meant from the tag name alone, nor the wiki excerpt really. Seeing what it's applied to, we might need it, but I would like it to have a different name.

Late January 2014: This tag is still here and still being used. We need to tag Ukraine questions with something at the moment, but I still do not like this name. I would like to see either "temporary" or "rapidly changing" in the name I think. Well, "temporally specific" would be better, but some people might think I was mis-spelling temporarily.

Answer (score 4):

It's not a terribly good name, to be sure.

Current events can have a notice added to them to this effect, and I think this should be sufficient. There's little need for a tag that groups all of these together, particularly as these won't be current for long, and the tag should then be removed. That alone should be an argument against it.

I'd rather see this one go away, and in case somebody steps up to it and makes their case for this tag, it will be gone soon.

At any rate, [current-events](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/current-events) sounds better.

Comment: _current-events_ will sound _current_ even after months or years.. don't like it.

Comment: I wouldn't want the tag removed afterwards. What we're trying to avoid is someone finding a question from 3 years ago and answering it "no, there's no problem with that, why on earth do you think there might be?" sort of thing.

Answer (score 4):

If such a tag must exist, then:

- [events](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/events)
- [events-related](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/events-related)
- [rapidly-changing-events](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rapidly-changing-events) -> inspired by the [post notice](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1499/what-is-the-post-is-related-to-a-rapidly-changing-event-flag).

I personally do not like the idea of such a tag, the post notice will be enough. I just wish there is a way to show the post notice even when listing the questions so we can see the notice before opening the question.

Comment: I like a simple "events" tag.